# Isolated storage reading data : System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I am writing the data and reading it, i am getting the exception as `"System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration"`,i am unable to figure it out whats the issue.

I have also added the exception that its printing.Please help me to solve the issue.

Here my code:

```
public static void WriteTopicState(Topic topic)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile("Stats.xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Topic));
                        serializer.Serialize(sw, topic);
                        serializer = null;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        public static Topic ReadMockTestTopicState()
        {
            Topic topic = null;
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    // Read application settings. 
                    if (isoStore.FileExists("Stats.xml"))
                    {
                        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile("Stats.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
                            {
                                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Topic));
                                topic = (Topic)serializer.Deserialize(SR);
                                serializer = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If setting does not exists return default setting.
                        topic = new Topic();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return topic;
        }
```

Exception :

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (9, 19). ---> 
System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 9, position 19.
```

**EDIT**

If there is any other way that i can save the data to a txt file also is fine for me, but only thing is i need to append the data to the existing document and read it get back the data.

Comment: Have you seen the EZ_Iso.dll yet? Handles all of the isolated storage garbage for you with a single method call. http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is because you are appending to your Stats.xml document, as a result it will contain multiple root elements once it has been written to more than once.

If you wish to only store the latest stats, you should use `FileMode.Create`:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(store.OpenFile("Stats.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
```

Valid XmlDocuments can only contain one root element, if you wish to store multiple 'stats' a different strategy is required:

- If writes are only creates (eg not updates) write out each topic to a different file and combine them when reading
- Create a container element that will store multiple topics and then parse this from disk, add to it, then subsequently overwrite the file on disk (you'll need to be careful with concurrency if you choose this option)
- Use a different storage medium than the file system (eg a document database, a SQL database, etc)
- Many other options

Comment: No i have to append multiple values, multiple times, so i have used Append, can you please help me to solve this ?

Comment: If there is other way to save the values like in txt file also , its fine for only thing is i need to append the data to the file and retrive the data back,

Comment: @user2056563 answer updated to list a few different strategies. I can't give you a one size fits all answer - it'll depend on your use case.

Comment: As i said before i just need to append the data, scenario is like this user plays and his score will be 20,22,23 and this for first attempt and then for 2nd attempt 10,22,13. so i have 2nd attempt that i need to update to the same file and when click taps on show results, it should display data with 2 attempts, please help me to acheive this, if you have a working example that would be great.And i am working on windows Phone 8 app development.